# PHP fopen() does not create a file

Tags: php, fopen

According to [fopen documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), in some modes it will create the file if it does not exist, but in my situation, I've checked all 'w', 'w+', 'x' and 'x+' modes but it's just throwing warnings at me and it cannot create the file.

It's my code:

```
$this->handle = fopen($this->log_name, 'w');
```

and what I get:

```
Warning: fopen(D:\xampp\htdocs\farid\logs\error.php) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\farid\libraries\error\log.php on line 34
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\farid\libraries\error\log.php on line 66
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\farid\libraries\error\log.php on line 27
```

And I'm working in windows environment.

Comment: File permissions is the most obvious suspect

Comment: From the same documentation - "If PHP has decided that filename specifies a local file, then it will try to open a stream on that file. The file must be accessible to PHP, so you need to ensure that the file access permissions allow this access. If you have enabled safe mode, or open_basedir further restrictions may apply."

Comment: Can you add more code? Maybe it's going wrong 1-2 line above your current code.

Comment: First the folder has to exist already. If it does, make sure it is writable.

Comment: @anyber Yes, Directory exists

Comment: @Mark Baker I'm on windows environment and there's no restricted permission in my project folder

Comment: @Robuust My rest of code is ok, trust me!

Comment: @anyber You were right, I had problems with my directory name!

Comment: @Jason Thanks man, you were right, problem was from my directory name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check if the path to the logfile exists, it creates a file, not a directory.

Also check if the user, which runs xampp, has access to the folder you specified.

Comment: Thanks for your help, there was a mistake in my directory name. now it's creating file. Is there any way so I even create the folder if it didn't exist in my fuunction?

Comment: check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php check the argument section look for "recursive", first you have to check if the file exists, `realpath` and and `file_exists` could be helpful

Comment: "it creates a file, not a directory" <-- indeed, that was it. Had to manually add a folder.