# Why does this call to fopen fail when all the other elements appear correct?

Tags: php, fopen

Yes, another question about `fopen()`... There are hundreds but none of them got this. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746540/php-fopen-does-not-create-a-file) is very similar, but after trying the answer (check permissions, check the tree exists), I still have this problem.

When trying to use `fopen` to create a file, I call the function and give it the required parameters, yet it throws a warning: "No such file or directory". However, checking the tree reveals the directory does indeed exist. The code goes like this:

```
$target_dir = "/files/" . usernameIs() . "/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"]);

...

$file = fopen($target_file, "w+");
fclose($file);
```

`$target_file` ends up containing `/files/ArtOfCode/icon.png` (the username is ArtOfCode and the `name` of the `uploadedFile` that I'm using to test is icon.png.

The directory tree looks like this:

```
public_html
  > /upload
    > /upload.php        (the calling script)
    > /action.php        (this script)
  > /files
    > /ArtOfCode
```

I get two warnings, both relating to `fopen()`:

```
Warning: fopen(/files/ArtOfCode/icon.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u875642593/public_html/upload/action.php on line 26
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u875642593/public_html/upload/action.php on line 27
```

So, I'm aware that the file (/files/ArtOfCode/icon.png) doesn't exist. However, the PHP docs say "...if the file does not exist, `fopen` will create it before trying to use it." The supporting directory tree **does** exist, so I'm stumped. How do I make this call create the file?

Comment: Try using `"../files/"` instead of `"/files/"` so that your path is relative.

Comment: ^^ right. `/files` is relative to your web _document root_.  `fopen()` and other filesystem operations operate on _filesystem_ paths.

Comment: It's not a relative path, it's absolute from public_html root. Do I need to use the full `/home/u875642593/public_html` path for absolute?

Comment: @ArtOfCode Yes, because `fopen()` only knows about the filesystem it lives on. If the path starts with `/`, it is assumed to be an absolute path, where `/files` resides at the FS root.

Comment: But `../files/` is okay too, or if you want it expanded to an absolute path, use `__DIR__ . "/../files/"` or `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/files'`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski So it's looking for `/files/etc` instead of `/home/u875642593/public_html/files/etc`. I see it. Care to post that as an answer?

Comment: @ArtOfCode there is no such thing as *absolute from public_html root*. **Absolute** is absolute. An absolute path always starts from the file system root directory (`/`).

Comment: @axiac okay, comin' up.

Comment: I am wrong. I deleted my previous comment about `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. It works fine for virtual hosts.

Comment: @axiac fair enough. My comment's gone too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's filesystem functions like `fopen()` and its siblings operate on *filesystem* paths, not on paths relative to your web server's document root ("web" paths). (They may also operate on streams like `http://example.com/file.txt` if your PHP installation is so configured, but that's not relevant here).

Since your path to `fopen()` begins with a `/`, the filesystem looks for it in the filesystem's root. A `/` at the beginning of a filesystem path always represents an *absolute* path rather than a relative one, and the directory structure doesn't actually exist in that absolute location.

You need to find the `files/` directory which resides in your web server's document root. Accessing it from a PHP script inside the `uploads/` directory, you can do that with the `..` pseudo-directory which means "one directory higher" and is a good way to get a *sibling* directory.

```
$target_dir = "../files/" . usernameIs() . "/";
```

The above results in a relative path. You can wrap it in [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to expand it to a full path.

I will more often use the `__DIR__` constant though, to get the directory of the current file and then traverse up with `..`

```
$target_dir = __DIR__ . "/../files/" . usernameIs() . "/";
```

Finally, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is an option as well. In your case, `files/` is inside the web server document root, so you may also use:

```
$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/files/" . usernameIs() . "/";
```

You might also consider defining a constant that retains the filesystem root of your application, which you can refer to throughout when doing `include/require` etc.

```
define("APPLICATION_ROOT", '/home/u875642593/public_html');
```

There isn't much to gain in your exact situation though, because your project is already at the document root. It does help if you need to move it to a different directory though, like if you kept a dev version in `/home/u875642593/public_html/dev`.